# How can I show data in listView in flutter using POST METHOD

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post

I want to display my data in list view with post method, I'm getting response in my console, but how to show the desired data in list view?

```
{
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "5 doctors found.",
    "Data": [
        {
            "DoctorId": "9",
            "EncDoctorId": "fXVmzecGStqrhx1PmIgwlQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr Ram Das",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/U7MK2MZGD0QVQ7E8IR7N.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "kj",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "5",
            "EncDoctorId": "pEl2B9kuumKRxIxLJO76eQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr.  Steve Buckner",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/IT02Z92IHFI48TMV6BUM.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "Eye",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "Frcs, md, mbbs",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "8",
            "EncDoctorId": "kFgorcFF0G6RQD4W+LwWnQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Alim Darr",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/VX4Q79ONBLQWIQ1ILQHF.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "FRCS",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "1",
            "EncDoctorId": "I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Mrs. Kusum Kumari Das",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/JVMK97QT9PSB8KQQ7NK1.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT, Interventional Cardiology, Medicine, Orthopetic, Specialisation, Endocrenology, Jeriasistic",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "MBBS DM (Cardiology)",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "2",
            "EncDoctorId": "7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Rejaul Alam",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/INFX2N9V5QFH712M2LEE.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "Orthopetic, Specialisation",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "MD, DM",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my main.dart where I'm calling the POST method.
by printing **print(data[0]["DoctorId"]);** im getting 9 which 1st doctorId.

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Http request"),
        ),
        body: Server(),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Server extends StatefulWidget {
  _ServerState createState() => _ServerState();
}

class _ServerState extends State<Server> {
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.post("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/alldoctor");
    // return json.decode(response.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> data = map["Data"];
    print(data[0]["DoctorId"]);
    print(data[0]["EncDoctorId"]);
    print(data[0]["DoctorName"]);
  }

  String _docId(dynamic doc) {
    return doc['doctorId'];
  }

  String _encDid(dynamic doc) {
    return doc['encDoctorId'];
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: fetchData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return (ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return (Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        // leading: CircleAvatar(
                        //   radius: 30,
                        //   backgroundImage:
                        //       // NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['image']),
                        // ),
                        title: Text(_docId(snapshot.data[index])),
                        subtitle: Text(_encDid(snapshot.data[index])),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
              }));
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you require any additional info from my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the data from `fetchData()` by using a `return` statement:

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.post("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/alldoctor");
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  return map["Data"];
}
```

Access the data using the name of the key in the `ListTile`:

```dart
ListTile(
  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['DoctorId']),
  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['EncDoctorId']),
)
```